# Blender 2.9 - better curve setup workflow?

Tags: texture-painting

I try to paint lines and curves in blender 2.90

the issue with curves (or masks) is that when you leave the view or close blender,or paint another texture... sometimes the curves are not at the same place for some reason

zooming in the 3d view makes it also more difficult to get back at the same spot

it's quiet tedious to work like this, especially when you have diffuse/specular/roughness/alpha/.... textures to draw

[image]

is there a way to make my life easier with this ?

thanks for your help

Comment: One option might be to make use of the built in addon for Stored Views https://youtu.be/S0ZJje8CvPs

Comment: interesting....